# ENV variables loading as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, omniauth

I am trying to run omniauth. I have my initializer as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :coinbase, ENV['CLIENT_ID'], ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'], scope: 'wallet:user:read wallet:user:email wallet:accounts:read'
end
```

with my client ID and secret saved in my .env file. When I boot my server, however, both of these variables are listed as nil. I can get the procedure to work when it is hard coded, but this is obviously not a good practice. How can I get the variables from my .env file into my initializer?

Comment: What do you use to load your `.env` file?

Comment: I am honestly not sure. I think I am using my secrets yml file. In the past, I have used pre-configured rails templates with this functionality built in; this is really my first time using vanilla rails. What are some methods which can be used to load the .env file?

Comment: Have you called `spring stop` and restarted the rails server?

Comment: I have; they continue to load as nil

Comment: Rails doesn't know about `.env` file. You should use a gem, `dotenv`.

Comment: just installed the dotenv gem, is there some sort of initial setup I need to do? The required values are still returning as nil when I boot my server.

Comment: @d00medman: have you read its readme?

Comment: -_- Just did, seems to have solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was solved by leveraging the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem and following the instructions in the readme